# UML Diagram: Reflexive Association with class instance clarification

Tags: java, uml

I used a plug-in in Eclipse Neon which is called ObjectAid, it's a plug-in that generates a UML Diagram automatically.

Now I understand everything in the generated UML except for one thing, which is the label next to the arrow "~class instance". What does that part mean?
[image: UML Diagram]

This is just an identical image, not the real one, of the UML generated so please understand that that's just an example.

EDIT:

```
//more codes here
static APAGenerator generateAPA = new APAGenerator();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        generateAPA.run();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
//more codes here
```

Comment: If you want a more precise answer, it could help that's you post the code of Class and the generated schema.

Comment: As @Kilian said, the name of the role is strange and the package visibilty is not often used. Do you really declare a package visibility ?

Comment: @granier, I already sorted it out and I'm no longer looking for an answer, thanks for the concern. Though for this part " Do you really declare a package visibility ?", no, I didn't specify any access modifier for the class instance I created. I've provided a code snippet above for the class instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can't speak for this ObjectAid (and what their makers thought they should do), but as per UML specification the `~` tells the visibility is `package` and it's followed by the role name which the association takes (IOW: the attribute being used). So the name is `class instance` which seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

@Helquin, you should code in java ?

If you do not specify the visibility the default is private-package. It explains the visibility.

Note: protected in java is also package (see [java visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)).

But instead having ~class instance, you should get an underlined ~generateAPA with a cardinality of 1.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added a Java tag now.

Comment: @Helquin, do not be sorry, it is always a pleasure to answer questions.