# UML relationship between the same class

Tags: uml

I have an 'Account' class and (every) Account (instance) can have 0 or more guestAccounts (from the same 'Account' class).

I'm stuck of how to model this:
- should I model this as a unary association (recursive)?

Thanks for helping.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed you can.

I am not sure that's solved your question, but you can do something like:

[image]

I define private for attributes visibility, public or default is often an error.

Comment: I already searched for similar schemas (without success), otherwise I hadn't posted my question here. Sorry, but not everyone is equally intelligent!

Comment: @ user1135780 have look to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250682/uml-diagram-reflexive-association-with-class-instance-clarification posted some days ago ? It is one example, a bad one but an example ...

Comment: @ user1135780  so now you should be able to provide a schema ... and we will analyze it.

Comment: One remark, maybe it was not clear, but a guest (Account) and also an Account can have only 1 Role (or maybe a better name would be "Permission" be it Read, Write or Both. Therefore, would it be better having an Enumeration (Read, Write, Both) instead of a Class? Using an Enum I suppose the multiplicity would then also be 1..1 (exactly 1 Role/Permission)? Thx.

Comment: Indeed with your schema an Account has several roles, this is the case usually. If an Account has only one role, and if the role list is defined, it is better to use an Enum. In this case, the constraint on the schema has to be changed.